# Run an XCode application through a shell script (jhbuild)

Tags: xcode, gtk, jhbuild

I'm developing a GTK+ application in XCode. For it to function correctly I need to use a special GTK+ script to set up a large number of environment variables:

```
jhbuild run path/to/compiled/binary
```

How can I override the "Run" function in XCode so that it will call the application this way?

(One workaround I have found is to create a new Aggregate build target that runs a shell script. This requires me to change the scheme between compiling the app and running it. This is semantically incorrect, and also causes the app to launch in the background.)